# FullCalendar using Database and Google Calendar

Tags: php, fullcalendar

It is possible to display both custom event coming from the database and Google Calendar using FullCalendar? I've done to display my custom event from database and I want to display also the holidays in my country using Google Calendar. My question is, it is possible to do that in FullCalendar? Here's my code:

```
googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyBTYvbg3gKLNi0A8qOXMyk6q-EnzM6DZq4',
events: [ googleCalendarId:'en.philippines#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',
  <?php foreach($events as $event): 

    $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
    $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
    if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
      $start = $start[0];
    }else{
      $start = $event['start'];
    }
    if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
      $end = $end[0];
    }else{
      $end = $event['end'];
    }
  ?>
    {
      id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
      title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
      start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
      end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
      color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
    },
  <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Okay thanks for helping. I try this link you gave. thank you

Comment: I added a full answer below with explanation, actually, please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`events: [ googleCalendarId:'en.philippines#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com'`...JS arrays can't contain named items...not sure this will even compile in the browser. Are you getting a console error, by any chance? Even if this was valid JS, you can't specify a google calendar as one item of your events array, fullCalendar is expecting "events" to be *either* a URL or an array of objects, not a combination. If you want to combine data from your database with data from an external source e.g. google calendar, then what you're probably looking for is "event sources" (see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSources)

This way you can give fullCalendar a list of different ways to get events. The first entry can be the data generated by your PHP code, and the second can be your Google Calendar details, which tell it to go away and download the events from Google Calendar:

Remove your `events:` option from the code and instead specify:

```
eventSources: [
  //first event source:
  [ 
    <?php foreach($events as $event): 

    $start = explode(" ", $event['start']);
    $end = explode(" ", $event['end']);
    if($start[1] == '00:00:00'){
      $start = $start[0];
    }else{
      $start = $event['start'];
    }
    if($end[1] == '00:00:00'){
      $end = $end[0];
    }else{
      $end = $event['end'];
    }
  ?>
    {
      id: '<?php echo $event['id']; ?>',
      title: '<?php echo $event['title']; ?>',
      start: '<?php echo $start; ?>',
      end: '<?php echo $end; ?>',
      color: '<?php echo $event['color']; ?>',
    },
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  ],
  //second event source:
  {
    googleCalendarId:'en.philippines#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com'
  }
]
```

N.B. If you want to incorporate Google Calendar events, make sure you've also followed al the steps outlined at https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar

Comment: @YadYoung no problem, if the answer has helped you please remember to mark it as "accepted" (click the tick next to the answer so it turns green) - thankyou :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do that with `addEventSource`:

```
$('#myCal').fullCalendar( ‘addEventSource’, source );
```

where

> ***Source*** may be an Array/URL/Function just as in the events option.
>   Events will be immediately fetched from this source and placed on the
>   calendar.

So, `source` could be either the Google url or an array with your events.

Comment: True but "addEventSource" is not really needed as a separate command, it can be included in the initial setup -  see https://fullcalendar.io/docs/google-calendar under the section "Multiple Google Calendars"

Comment: I didn't notice that. At this point, I wonder why this post was created since the OP's code looks correct.

Comment: Actually now you made me look closely I've just realised, the code is not correct at all - they are defining `events: [ googleCalendarId:'en.philippines#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com'`...JS arrays can't contain named items...not sure this will even compile in the browser

Comment: You're right!! So, `events` should be an array of events and `eventSources` an array with a single object with the GC id, right?

Comment: well you'd define the eventSources parameter, which is expected to be an array, and one entry in the array is an object containing the GC ID, and the other entry is an array containing the events which are output by PHP. You can't use `events` an `eventSources` together in the same setup. `events` is shorthand for having one event source. Once you have more than one, you remove that, and make the content which was in it simply one of the items within `eventSources`.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
eventSources: [{googleCalendarId: 'xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com', className: 'gcal-event'},{url:'events.php',}],
```

Comment: For long term value, please explain why this code solves OP's issue. Code only answers are frowned upon. Explanations help future visitors learn, and apply this knowledge to similar issues that have in their own code. They are also more likely to be upvoted. Consider editing to improve your answer, and keep quality of SO Answers high. Thanks for your contribution.